# Why does the place where I import js file affects my invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a simple test js file(`test.js`) as below:

```
jQuery("#h2t").click(function() {
    alert("123");
});
```

Then I include it in a jsp page(`test.jsp`):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="h2t" href="#">test link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't work when I click on the `test link` hyperlink. If I move the include code `after the <a> tag`, it works fine:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="h2t" href="#">test link</a>
        <script src="resources/js/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone tell me why the order affects the invocation of a method, and how can I just include the js file in `<head>` field and still make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not "importing" anything... it's called an "include".

Answer (score 2):

call it in document.ready function

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#h2t").click(function() {
        alert("123");
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#h2t").click(function() {
            alert("123");
        });
   });
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I'm new to JQuery, sorry.. Could you just give me the code how to call it in `document.ready function`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The order is very important. When the script is loaded in the head any immediately executing code runs. If that code looks for any elements on the page, such as one with `id=h2t` then it will not find that element because the page hasn't rendered yet, and consequently nothing will be done.

When the script is loaded in the body then any elements rendered above the script's location in the page will be visible. When an element is rendered, it is added to the DOM ([Document Object Model](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)) which allows it to be located. That is why the script loaded in the page properly executes.

A common way to get around this is to wait for the document to finish loading all of the elements. jQuery has a nice handler for this called [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), and there is this shorthand notation for it:

```
$(function(){
 //code to run when the document loads
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The page loaded from top to bottom, so in the first script your js is executed before the `#h2t` is created so you will not be able to select it.
In your second script your js is executed after `#h2t` was created in the dom so it is available to select with `jQuery("#h2t")`.

If you don't want to place your js after the element or at the end of the page you can use [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) this will wait until the entire dom is loaded then execute the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#h2t").click(function() {
        alert("123");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the element `#h2t` does not yet exist when the event binding is called. In the second example that element has loaded when the binding is called.

You should wrap your binding call with a `$.ready()`:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    jQuery("#h2t").click(function() {
        alert("123");
    });
});
```

... or use delegation:

```
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#h2t', function() {
        alert("123");
    });
```